# Database design for hourly, weekly, ranking?

Tags: mysql, ranking

I've been trying to figure out a good way to handle a ranking system of this sort.  As a rough example, I would like to query a facebook page and grab the likes and comments of each post.  Then, there would be three rankings based on a time interval.  To give a simplified example:

```
Hourly
- I pull all the posts updated within the last hour, and compare the # of likes/comments compared to my previous entry (the last pull being an hour prior).

Daily
- I pull down all posts within a 24 hours date range.  I compare the # of likes/comments compared to the previous entry. "Post X had 12 more likes and 40 more comments today compared to yesterday"

Weekly
- I pull down all posts within a week's range and do the same as above.  "Post X had no new likes, but 10 more comments added this week compared to last week"
```

In terms of the DB tables, what would be a good way to handle this?  Would it make sense to have one giant table with the posts (title, comments_previous, comments_current, likes_previous, likes_current, etc)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns: (PK)timestamp, (index)pageid, count. Set a new timestamp every hour on the hour for pages that are liked. Timestamp is the PK so that you don't get horrible fragmentation from your clustered index / page layout in the database.

If you feel for performance reasons that you need to de-normalize, you can make additional daily and monthly tables that are rolled-up summations. Likely, you'll be able to efficiently generate what you need without the rollup tables by using where clauses on the time / pageid combination, thereby giving you what you need with just one table.

Purge old data as you see fit, or keep it.

---

### Clarification

When a comment receives a like, do the following:

```
insert into likeRanking (concat(select left(now(),13), '00:00'), commentid, 1)
    on duplicate key update score = score + 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  Does it make any difference to your solution since I am collecting data on all the posts of a page, rather than the page itself?

Comment: You can do it by post just as well as by page. I think the value of the structure remains.

Comment: I'm sorry, I need to clarify.  If a page (or post) keeps having new comments or likes, and if the timestamp keeps getting updated at that time, then how would I be able to access data from a week ago?  

Or perhaps, did you mean that when a page has a change in the number of comments or likes, then I create a new row in the table with the same pageid (index), but with an updated timestamp(pk)? Can you have identical indexes in a table?

Answer (score -1):

I would do this as follows:

Create a table that gets the time now, comments now, and likes now.

Then after an hour of that time, create another table that gets the time now, comments now and likes now, then subtract it to the previously created table. Then drop the other table and insert the new values of the new table. Then after an hour, create another table.

Same with monthly and yearly.

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Create a table every hour? No. Naughty.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  Is this a common way to approach such scenarios?  I had thought about having six tables, then simply truncate the "previous" table, but this seemed to be a waste of space. 

In your solution, if I understand correctly, the only time there are two tables for each time interval (hourly, daily, weekly) would be at the data fetch time itself?

Comment: Precisely. Two tables would only exist when they fetch data. So definitely, this wouldn't be a waste of space. The other table gets updated by the new table every hour, day, or week after it has computed the difference. This is just my idea, though. This is the way I would approach things. Just a follow-up question. Do you want this to show every login?

Comment: then this would be easy. Just get the logout time. every logout get the time and the date. Then when the user logs in, you can get all the likes, date and time then get the difference of the two. That should be all.